# C# Formatting in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, formatting

My question is fairly simple:

Visual studio offers settings for formatting the code. However I was not able to fix this:

I want this

> ReturnType FunctionName(){ .. }

instead of

> ReturnType FunctionName() { .. }

So I want to get rid of the space between `()` and `{}`. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious: How did you get the space `there` at the first place?

Comment: Its the default setting :(

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C#

Inside there you can find lots of ways to format your text. It is hard to say what you want from your post but anything formatting is a good start to look there.

Comment: The place in my post where it says "I dont want a space there", it means I don't want a space there, as far as I could see, there is no formatting option for that.